# Why would the following command take down a server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

So, I was testing my site for SQL injection using Rapid7's guide, and part of it said:

Check for sa -

```
SELECT+ASCII(SUBSTRING((a.loginame),1,1))
+FROM+master..sysprocesses+AS+a
+WHERE+a.spid+=+@@SPID)=115
```

Following this, the site immediately crashed and won't reload. I assumed that due to it being a "check", it wouldn't actually affect the server itself. Is there a reason why this apparently took down the server?

Thank you.

Edit: It came back up after approximately 15 minutes.

Comment: At least get the product tag right: the above has nothing to do with mysql, it is for ms sql server.

Comment: can you show more of your code? I'm guessing that all of the + signs are because you're using dynamic SQL and the query you are building isn't what you intended.

Comment: Check the logs and look for expensive queries around the time of failure.  You would be amazed at how simple 1 row queries (zombied) can bring down servers

Answer (score 0):

Even if your query was somehow "dangerous", it by no means could lock up the server. Those tables are are not referenced in your regupar operations, and do not have the size anyways to pose any kind of IO threat.

First, lets start by why you were looking for a specific SPID in the first place. What was this session doing? Why did you feel the need to lookup a session ID in the first place? Yes, i know you were testing...but surely you have a reason here beyond following verbatim a guide.

Second, look at the logs and the latest queries that the system cached before the crash. Was there any large, monstrous IO? Updates, Merges? Anything expensive DDL/DML? Did several queries lock?

Was there any services that spiked during this time? (Note this should not interfere, unless the sysadmin forgot to allocate memory to SQL Server)

Clearly there is more to this story, and you need to find out.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a reason why this apparently took down the server?

No, there is no reason why this apparently took down the server.
You are missing the relevant code.
This does nothing.

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment.

Comment: @Shadow, I had "No, ", so now it is definitly an answer for the question "Is there a reason why this apparently took down the server?"

Comment: Well, I agree that this is not the reason for bringing server down. This is not even a valid SQL. This is some pseudo-code or part of a third program. Another thing is "site was down" - this is not specific at all. What was down? MS SQL SERVER? I doubt it a lot. One more thing is: where did you put this "injection" to? I assume this is not the full code that was executed at sql server.